# Configuring collectionView:cellForRowAt based on an array of strings

Tags: ios, json, swift

I've got this JSON data (not verbatim) that I get from the backend. It contains the actual data and an array of strings describing the sequence of cells to be shown:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "text",
            "data": {
                "text": "some text"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "pic",
            "data": {
                "url": "https://somepic.jpg",
                "text": "picture"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "switcher",
            "data": {
                "id": 1,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": 0,
                        "text": "option 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "text": "option 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "text": "option 3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],

    "view": [
        "text",
        "pic",
        "switcher",
        "text"
    ]
}
```

The problem is that I can't get my head around how to configure cellForRowAt: and get the **right order of cells in one section**. (i.e. text, pic, selector, text).

I tried a couple of things:

1. **Looping** through "view" array and **switching** on each individual view string to dequeue a specific cell but that doesn't seem to work since returning a cell from a switch case gives a "unexpected non-void return value in void function" error.
2. I was also thinking about **turning a "view" array into a dictionary** and then, based on keys in it, dequeue a specific cell but then again, a dictionary should have unique keys meaning that I will not have 2 "text" entries, one of them will be lost.

So, the questions is: **how can I dequeue specific cells based on the array of strings?** It's also important to understand that it should be done in **one section**. I'm feeling that it's somehow not that difficult to implement but I'm kinda lost right now. Thanks!

Comment: Makes no sense.You have a view array `["text", "pic",  "selector", "text"]` but nothing in your JSON whose key is `"selector"`. And what could the repetition of `"text"` possibly signify? No computer program on earth could parse this. No human can parse it. This isn't JSON, it's just madness.

Comment: Hi Denis, can you, please, specify on what string you want to dequeue the collection view cell? I would hope that string you need to dequeue on has a limited amount of variations?

Comment: @matt My bad, instead of "selector" there should've been "switcher". As for the repetition of "text", as I understand, "text" cell should be shown twice.

Comment: @MacUserT Hi! So, as you can see from JSON, there's an array called "view" that has strings that basically represent cells I need to show. The idea is that in collection view cells should be shown in order they are represented in the "view" array, i.e. "text" cell, "pic" cell, "switcher" cell and then again "text" cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to transform your view list and data array into an array of cell contents that you can use inside the TableViewDelegate and TableViewSource method :

```
var cellsContents : [Int] = []
for aView in view {
var found = false
var index = 0
for aData in data {
    if !found {
        if let name = aData["name"] as? String {
            if aView == name {
                found = true
                cellsContents.append(index)
                continue
            }
        }
        index = index + 1
    }
}
```

}

Then :

- number of rows : cellsContents.count
- type and contents for a row : data[cellsContents[indexPath.row]]["name"] and data[cellsContents[indexPath.row]]["data"]

Comment: Thanks a lot, seemed to work very well! I'm curious, is this a frequent pattern? I mean, an array of views determining the sequence of content (or cells) to show. Never met anything like that before.

Comment: I do not know. May be the date comes from 2 places : one with all  details and one with the list of items to display. In this case the changes in the details do not impact the list of items. But that is just a supposition.